# Learning SVN properly

Tags: svn, repository, svn-checkout

I'm very new with using SVN. But I have used GIT for a year and never had so much trouble doing some the simplest(?) things.

I am having an easy time creating a new SVN repo on my local machine (Mac). I understand leaving a `commit`, viewing the commit log, checking the status of modified files, etc. But I'm having the hardest time pulling a repo/syncing changes from a previously set up SVN repo on a server.

When I run:

```
svn co http://subdomain.site.com
```

I get:

```
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://subdomain.site.com ': 200 OK (http://subdomain.site.com)
```

Double and triple checked the URL. Far as I can tell, I am doing something way wrong when pulling a repo from a subdomain. (have managed to pull and sync from a non-subdomain before...once) I have watched/read many tutorials. Most skips past where I have issues. I would rather use GIT but some of the old sites I mess with use SVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link http://svn.haxx.se/dev/archive-2010-01/0211.shtml strongly suggest that even after triple checking the url it is probably wrong.

Btw: most subversion repositories behind a http server have longer url's. For instance http://svnserver.insomedomain.com/svn/svnrepository/trunk/project

or http://svnserver.insomedomain.com/svn/svnrepository/tags/project/v1.0

Comment: So, on any domain, you have to use svn.siteurl.com/fo/foo/etc basically?

Comment: Yes. It's very rare to serve a single repository out of the root of the web server. You *can*, but it's just not done in 99% of cases. Whoever configured your repository should be able to give you the URL you need to check out. But don't check out the whole repository - only check out the portion you need (like trunk, or a specific branch). Otherwise you'll fill your hard drive with tags & branches you wontt ever touch.

Comment: @GerritCap Ahhh ok, makes since. Yes tried using http://svn.siteulr.com/fo/foo and it worked finally (all I needed was the svn at the front, thought that was a subdomain). Finally able to pull from the server repo and commit like normal. Thanks so much.